# Column string to time

Tags: time, google-bigquery, casting, converters

New in SQL here! I use BigQuery.
How do I convert an entire string column to time?
The column name is ride_length and it's format is 00:00 (minutes:seconds).
On schema is string but I need it to be time.
Also how can I calculate its average then?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are multiple ways to do it. But, it totally depends on how you need the end result (or even process the intermediate values). One way is you could possibly calculate the total seconds using split, cast & add, do the average & cast it back to time datatype (or maintain in minutes/seconds)

```
WITH
  s AS (
  SELECT
    '45:00' AS time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '30:00' AS time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '20:00' AS time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '25:00' AS time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '04:00' AS time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '25:30' AS time )
SELECT
  avg_s,
  time(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(avg_s))
FROM (
  SELECT
    CAST(AVG(secs) AS INT64) AS avg_s
  FROM (
    SELECT
      time,
      SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(time, ':') [ORDINAL(1)] AS INT64)*60+ SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(time, ':') [ORDINAL(2)] AS INT64) AS secs
    FROM
      s ) )
```

[image]